# Hashmap with class

Tags: java

```
class PlayerNames {

        String OrigName;
        String TagName;
        //String DispName;

        PlayerNames(String OrigName,String TagName) {
            this.OrigName = OrigName;
            this.TagName = TagName;
            //this.DispName = DispName;
        }
    }
HashMap<PlayerNames, Integer> PlayerTempNeutral = new HashMap<PlayerNames, Integer>();
PlayerTempNeutral.put(new PlayerNames(new String("Bob"),new String("BobsWindshield"), 1);
PlayerTempNeutral.put(new PlayerNames(new String("Ron"),new String("RonsDoor"), 1);
```

how do I grab Bob and then BobsWindshield using this class? I basically wanted 3 values and I found this snippet on google but I don't know how to "get" the value. I want to get based on OrigName or "Bob"
Something like

```
If(PlayerTempNeutral.OrigName == "Bob"){
 String CarPart = PlayerTempNeutral.TagName; //This would show BobsWindshield ONLY
}
```

I tried googling examples of Hashmaps but they only showed the single digits and none were really clear with using classes

Comment: you can't do a get from a Map with a partial key.

Comment: A partial key? I don't quite understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things to be corrected here, I'll attempt to address the ones I see.

*Firstly*, the Java standard is to use lowercase names for variables. Makes it very difficult to read otherwise, as everything looks like a type name.

*Second*, Never use `new String()` to create a new string Object. Java strings are immutable, and the JVM maintains a pool of strings used in the application. A string created with `new String()` will create a brand new copy from the string passed to that constructor, which is **not** drawn from that pool, but separately allocated (so in effect, unnecessarily allocating more memory for a string object which may already exist in the pool). Instead just pass the strings like `"bob"` and `"BobsWindshield"`.

*And finally*, to answer the question directly, since your exact use-case is uncertain, your solution might not even need a Hash. You might be able to get away with using an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead, if you just care about plain simple storage of multiple objects of the same type.

However, in order to use a [`HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), you need to keep in mind that a Hash / Map is a collection of Key-Value pairs. Your current implementation is essentially non-sensical if your intention is to store and index multiple `PlayerNames` objects. Do this instead:

```
HashMap<String, PlayerNames> playerTempNeutral = new HashMap<String, PlayerNames>();
playerTempNeutral.put("Bob", new PlayerNames("Bob", "BobsWindshield");
playerTempNeutral.put("Ron", new PlayerNames("Ron", "RonsDoor");
```

In this example, "Bob" or "Ron" is the key, and the corresponding `PlayerNames` object is the value relating to that key.

In order to get one of those objects from the collection, you simply do so using the key (or "index value", I guess you could call it):

```
PlayerNames bob = playerTempNeutral.get("bob");
```

And of course, once you have your `bob` object, you can play with it as needed (ex: `bob.TagName`).

I suspect this may not necessarily be your use-case, so you'll have to elaborate more if you need additional information.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay so how would I reference BobsWindshield/Ronsdoor?

Comment: @GinzoMilani Just made an update. Forgot to add how to get stuff from a hash.

Answer (score 1):

You should override hashcode and equals method of Object class in your PlayerNames class.

As you want to get on basis of OrigName instance variable only only so use only this in hashcode method while calculating hashcode and in equals method while comparison.

EDIT:
Updated your class

class PlayerNames {

```
    String OrigName;
    String TagName;
    //String DispName;

    PlayerNames(String OrigName,String TagName) {
        this.OrigName = OrigName;
        this.TagName = TagName;
        //this.DispName = DispName;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(o instanceof PlayerNames){
            PlayerNames p = (PlayerNames)o;
            return ( p.OrigName == this.OrigName);
        }
        else
            return false;

    }
    @Override
    public int hashCode(){
        int hashcode=0;
        int MOD=10007;
        int shift=29;
        for(int i=0;i<OrigName.length();i++){
            hashcode=((shift*hashcode)%MOD+OrigName.charAt(i))%MOD;
        }
        return hashcode; 
    }
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return OrigName;
    }
}
```

For put and get operations I have written below class

```
import java.util.HashMap;
public class MainThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PlayerNames Bob = new PlayerNames(new String("Bob"),new String("BobsWindshield"));
        HashMap<PlayerNames, Integer> PlayerTempNeutral = new HashMap<PlayerNames, Integer>();
        PlayerTempNeutral.put(Bob,100);
        Integer p =  PlayerTempNeutral.get(Bob);
        System.out.println(p);

    }
}
```

Use above code for experiment purpose only , as it is a bad coding practice. As you are a new java programmer understanding concepts is more important then best practice.

Comment: I'm pretty new at java so you have to elaborate :(

Comment: please go through http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/10/09/working-with-hashcode-and-equals-methods-in-java/ , It has sample class with equals and hashcode meethod

Comment: @GinzoMilani , in another answer Teeg has given good explanations but as you are new to java I will update my answer with your updated class.